# What is a complexity of a doubly-connected edge list?

Tags: geometry, data-structure

What is a complexity of a doubly-connected edge list?

Is it a number of half edges plus the number of the faces plus the number of the vertices?

Comment: I don't know how a doubly-connected edge list is interpreted, nor what it's used for.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) is what I mean.